# ADC injection current and supply voltage

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, diodes, injection-current

I'm using a [PIC18F](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC18F26-45-46-Q10-Data-Sheet-40001996E.pdf) MCU.

I am using an ADC reference of 3.3 V. If I want to measure 4 V, what would happen? Would the internal ADC peripheral get damaged or will the ADC work fine, and show the maximum value?

It is mentioned one should not apply more than 300 mV outside the supply rails. If the ADC input got more than the supply rail, then what would the PIC controller behavior be?

Also, the clamp current is mentioned as 20 mA which must be distributed across all the I/O pins. What if I provide a clamping current of 20 mA to each pin? The internal diodes would get stressed and lead to failure? I assume the internal pins have only diodes and not resistors. I couldn't find any info on the internal clamping diodes and resistors in the datasheet.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? Why do you want to operate the MCU outside its specification?

Comment: @thebusybee, I am just curious to understand what would happen in those cases? I do not want to operate in those conditions. Just understanding what would be the effects.

Answer (score 4):

> I am using an ADC reference of 3.3 V. If I want to measure 4 V, what would happen? Would the internal ADC peripheral get damaged or will the ADC work fine, and show the maximum value?

You need to check the *Electrical Specifications* in chapter 39:

[image]

[image]

<sup>Source: [PIC18F26/45/46Q10 Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC18F26-45-46-Q10-Data-Sheet-40001996E.pdf)</sup>

So it all depends what V<sub>DD</sub> is in your case. It could be anywhere between 1.8..5.5 V (Table 39-1) under operating conditions.

So if V<sub>DD</sub> is below 3.7 V you might damage your device. I would also treat any V<sub>DD</sub> below 4.0 V as if it were below the absolute max value, because it's a grey area.

And if it's at 4.0 V or above the ADC value would simply clip at the max value.

As @[MattS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/115106/matt-s) commented, you always have to meet the specifications of -0.3 V to (V<sub>DD</sub> + 0.3 V). So if your device is unpowered (i.e. V<sub>DD</sub> = 0 V), V<sub>PIN</sub> mustn't exceed +0.3 V.

Another input by @[TimWilliams](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/311631/tim-williams):

> One more note -- in the process of injecting current, the pin voltage may rise above VDD+0.3V. The current and voltage limits shall be understood inclusively, i.e. voltages higher than this are acceptable (again, for survival purposes) if the current limits are respected.

Here is a discussion on the Microchip forums that supports this assertion: [PIC16LF18324 ADC input higher than Vref+](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m959328.aspx)

---

> Also, the clamp current is mentioned as 20 mA which must be distributed across all the I/O pins. What if I provide a clamping current of 20 mA to each pin? The internal diodes would get stressed and lead to failure? I assume the internal pins have only diodes and not resistors. I couldn't find any info on the internal clamping diodes and resistors in the datasheet.

You find this answer also in the same table in chapter 39.1 *Absolute Maximum Ratings*:

[image]

[image]

If you apply a clamp current of ±20 mA to each pin, you'll definitely fry your MCU. You must also meet the specifications for maximum current and total power dissipation, which you'll exceed.

This question may also add some further insights: [What is meant by Input clamp current/Output Clamp current in micro controller datasheet?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71479/what-is-meant-by-input-clamp-current-output-clamp-current-in-micro-controller-da)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, If I apply 4V at the ADC input when the ADC reference is 3.3V, I won't be damaging the chip? The value will be the maximum value only?

Comment: Yes, as long as VDD is 4V or above. Otherwise the datasheet would be inaccurate.

Comment: Thank you. Could you clarify on the clamping current questions?

Comment: "So it all depends what VDD is in your case. It could be anywhere between 1.8..5.5 V." Minor quibble: VDD can also be 0 V when your power is off. Applying a voltage that is in-range when the chip is powered may have unpredictable effects if you apply it when the chip is off.

Comment: @MattS Good point, I didn't think about the obvious, I'll update my answer.

Comment: One more note -- in the process of injecting current, the pin voltage may rise above VDD+0.3V. The current and voltage limits shall be understood inclusively, i.e. voltages higher than this are acceptable (again, for survival purposes) if the current limits are respected.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for this input. I'll quote this verbatim.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Some devices have input circuitry which can clamp small currents to the rail without adversely affecting operation, but that isn't universally true.  I worked with a design used a shift register chip (74HC family, IIRC) whose inputs were connected through 10K resistors to sources which had a 12-volt swing, yielding a clamp current of 0.7mA.  Unfortunately, one manufacturer's chip was fabricated in such a way that feeding 0.7mA into one pin above VDD would result in much of the current flowing into the adjoining input, pulling it high.

Comment: @supercat Indeed, have measured some 74HC (name brand) myself; the input structure resembles a PNP with its emitter to the pin, base to VDD, collector to VSS and adjacent pins. The hFE is quite pitiful, ~1 to VSS, ~0.03 to adjacent pins -- but this can indeed be enough to muck with say a low-current schmitt trigger timer circuit where the leakage would be a problem. Or apparently other mfgs may be worse, as you say.

Comment: @TimWilliams: I remember that a maximal voltage on one input would pull the adjacent input above the logic switching threshold, but I don't remember the resistor values or what the threshold was.  I do remember being really confused by what was going on until I looked at the pins which were "erroneously" reading high on a scope.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the effect:

Analog pins are generally sensitive to injected current.  Whether that's true of the PIC18 family and ADC, who knows.  It's not clear from the datasheet whether this is the case.  Many other devices suggest zero injection while analog functions are in use on respective pins / IO banks.

Simply, the most likely result is ADC readings out of tolerance.  Maybe it'll still read 0x03ff anyway, maybe it'll be marginal (erroneous at min clock, max. temp., etc.), maybe it reads zeroes or gibberish.

It's not likely to cause CMOS latchup if the current limit is respected in the process, but supplying a hard-fixed (excess) voltage to a pin is likely to cause much more current flow.  Typically ~100mA is required to induce latchup.

See: [Quality Handbook - Microchip](https://www.microchip.com/content/dam/mchp/documents/quality---reliability/00000169J.pdf) It appears they rate their products to 200mA, even; though the exact nature of those tests isn't given and you'd have to find the underlying standard to see.

Contact the manufacturer for more information.